# Silverlight Viewbox not working with IE9

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer-9, viewbox

I'm developing a silverlight application for use on small and large monitors,

I had the code working perfectly, my main page contains a viewbox and all controls are children of that viewbox and they did scale correctly, i've been testing on IE9 the whole time.

Recently VS2010 crashed which is does quite frequently when dealing with silverlight, ever since this crash IE9 refuses to display my Viewbox correctly.

Chrome / Opera / Firefox / Safari all have the correct behaviour but not IE9 anymore.

When the application starts, its initial size is correct but after a few seconds it seems to break out of the viewbox.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Viewbox MinHeight="600" MinWidth="800">
    <Grid Width="1024" Height="768" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="25">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <sdk:Frame Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource FrameStyle}" Source="{Binding SelectedPage.PageUri}" NavigationFailed="Frame_NavigationFailed" />
        <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="#FFD4D2D2" Background="White" BorderThickness="1 0 1 1">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
               ...
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

the following images show what the page looks like in IE and Chrome.

**Chrome at roughly 800x600 (Correct)**
[image: Chrome Scaling Correctly]

**IE at roughly 800x600 (Incorrect)**
[image: IE Scaling incorrectly]

Both are using the same XAP file the app was never run on chrome before so it shouldnt have been cached, either way the cache was cleared before testing.

Has anyone had a problem similar to this before? are there any work arounds to make this work on IE?

Is this a bug with silverlight or IE?

Any help would really be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling/reinstalling Silverlight?

Comment: no I haven't, but if it was silverlight not working, would it not break on chrome also?

I'll try reinstalling now though just incase

Comment: Have you control-mouse-wheel zoomed the IE display by any chance? You have specified minimum display sizes on the ViewBox, so you should probably contain that ViewBox in a ScrollViewer in case it does not fit.

Comment: @HiTech That seemed to fix it, I don't remember zooming in on IE but zooming out worked. Thanks

Comment: +1 for highlighting a common problem we are seeing with people's layouts... make sure you always test Silverlight with mouse wheel zooming :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you control-mouse-wheel zoomed the IE display by any chance?

You have specified minimum display sizes on the ViewBox, so you should probably contain that ViewBox in a ScrollViewer in case it does not fit.